# Keycloak cannot connect to my MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, keycloak

I'm trying to link up my Keycloak server to my local `MySQL` database. I have scala projects running on the side and the mysql connection url used there is `host.docker.internal:30003`

So I'm trying to use the same url for my keycloak instance:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL -e DB_ADDR=host.docker.internal:30003 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak -e MYSQL_USERNAME=keycloak -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=keyCloak@123 -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG -e KEYCLOAK_USER=kc-admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.2
```

But I see this in the logs:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: host.docker.internal:30003: Name or service not known
```

In MySQL my user `keycloak` is created and I've granted all privileges to it.

Does the problem lie with my database url?

Comment: "Name or service not known" means the hostname failed to resolve.

Comment: but if i do this: `curl host.docker.internal:30003 --output mysql.txt -v` I don't see an error (I see a weird output but not a failure)

Comment: It could be that your local machine can resolve the `.internal` address but within a container it can't.

Comment: I guess that makes sense

Comment: Check https://medium.com/@shubhamdhote9717/keycloak-deployment-on-kubernetes-cluster-834bee73a567